# RISC V linker cannot find -lgcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, riscv, gnu-toolchain

I'm trying to compile C code for GCC, but the linker is unable to find libgcc.
I want to compile some simple tests for an RV32I core.

When I try to use the modulo operator, GCC generates a call to the soft implementation of
the mod instruction.

```
call    __modsi3
```

But linking fails because I think im missing `libgcc`

```
test.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `__modsi3'
```

This is my compilation command:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -lm -lgcc -static -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  crt0.s -O0
```

These are my linker options:

```
-lgcc -b elf32-littleriscv -m elf32lriscv
```

If I try to use the `-lgcc` option on the linker, it will throw the following error:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: cannot find -lgcc
```

I also tried to provide directly the path of `libgcc.a`. But it didn't help.
I got the path of `libgcc.a` this way:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv32i -print-libgcc-file-name
```

I added the path directly to my compilation command like so:

```
-L="/mnt/c/Users/camin/Documents/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/10.2.0/libgcc.a"
```

Also, the way I compiled the toolchain might be the issue, I'm using the RISCV toolchain with `multi-lib` support

I followed the instructions from https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain
with some slight modification (`-j12`)

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/riscv --enable-multilib
make -j12
```

This also installed the toolchain so I didn't had to `make install`

Thanks.

Comment: I got the impression that riscv multilib is fairly broken. If you have the option to rebuild the toolchain specifically for your arch, that's probably your best bet. Quoting https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/issues/425 " It is simpler to just build a different compiler for each linux arch/abi combination you need."

Comment: Also I bet that libgcc.a is actually 64 bit. You can take it apart using `ar x` and then run `file` on the objects inside.

Comment: How did you call the linker? Did you use the linker directly, or via `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `-L="/mnt/c/Users/camin/Documents/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/10.2.0/libgcc.a"` you must only give the path to the `L` option. Your option should be :`-L="/mnt/c/Users/camin/Documents/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/10.2.0"`

the enable-multilib is working well, it only provide libraries for set of archs. However be careful to give the path of the libgcc corresponding to your arch. When you enable multilib the default one will be a 64 bit versions. Normally for rv32i, the option you need is :`-L="/mnt/c/Users/camin/Documents/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/10.2.0/rv32i/ilp32"`.

If you don't give the good library you will probably get  `ABI is incompatible with that of the selected emulation` error.

It would be easier to use the `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` driver to make the link because he knows all the options better. Normally it will find the necessary libraries (libgcc, libgloss ....) automatically for your arch.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to let GCC handle the linking, LD has no idea how to find the required libraries.

Comment: @yflelion: You shuold never call `ld` by land. Use `gcc` to invoke the linker (`collect2` and `ld`). `gcc` will add many additional options to the linker call(s) which you will have a hard time to work out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, had to manually add the path to the libgcc.a as an argument to elf-ld:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-ld -o exampleProg2.elf -T bram.ld -m elf32lriscv -nostdlib --no-relax /(RVTOOLCHAIN_GCC_LIB_DIR)/libgcc.a
```

Just be careful of choosing the right libgcc.a, there may be multiple in your installation, depending of your multilib seutp.

Comment: You don't want to call the linker by hand. Instead, use `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv32i`.  This will call the linker with appropriate options like `-L`, `-lgcc` etc. also notice that the order of command line option *does* matter.